# GetOverlappedResult return true,but no data write

Tags: api, winapi

I check async write with following code.

```
BOOL bOk = ::GetOverlappedResult(hFile, pOverlapped, dwBytesTransferred, TRUE);
if ( FALSE == bOk )
{
     TRACE_ERROR_NO_ASSERT(GetOverlappedResult);
}
```

bOk is TRUE, but dwBytesTransferred is 0, and pOverlapped->Internal is 258(timeout).

my questionn is : is my async operation timeout and will be finished later? or just failed? should I call CancelIo to cancel this timeout operation like this?

```
BOOL bOk = ::GetOverlappedResult(hFile, pOverlapped, dwBytesTransferred, TRUE);
if ( FALSE == bOk )
{
     TRACE_ERROR_NO_ASSERT(GetOverlappedResult);
     return FALSE;
}

if ( 0 == dwBytesTransferred )
{
   CancelIoEx(hFile, pOverlapped); //  is this neccessary?
}
```

I refer the MSDN document, but no description for this condition.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You are asking for somebody to write you a manual, it isn't going to solve your problem.   You need to post more repro code.  Show the SetCommTimeouts() and DCB initialization code, talk about the handshaking requirements of the device, mention whether you've ever been able to send anything.

Comment: @HansPassant - this really win32 layer bug (well known), that status code >=0 is lost

Comment: most of time, I can send the data correctly. this(write 0 byte, but GetOverlappedResult return TRUE) happend rarely! I don't know how to reproduce this again.below is DCB init code.
  DCB dcb = { sizeof(DCB) };
  if ( FALSE == GetState(dcb) )
  {
   TRACE_ASSERT_ERROR(GetState);
   return FALSE;
  }
  
  dcb.BaudRate = baud;
  dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
  dcb.ByteSize = 8;
  dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
  dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
  dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
  dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
  dcb.fOutX = FALSE;
  dcb.fInX = FALSE;

Comment: anyway serial port can some time return `STATUS_TIMEOUT`. this not developer error. simply no data to read and timeout expired. but that win32 layer lost this status (process it like 0 status) already windows bug. in this case better look for `(NTSTATUS)OVERLAPPED.Internal` or use nt api `ZwReadFile` and `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` direct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your operation is finished (failed) with `STATUS_TIMEOUT` - this is final status and operation complete. you not need and can not cancel it - it **finished**. that `GetOverlappedResult` return TRUE and not set error code - this is only bad (I be say error) design of this win32 api. it unconditionally return `TRUE` and not set last error if `(0 <= status)`. as result it wrong process `STATUS_TIMEOUT` (I think you worked with serial (com) port).

so formal answer:

1. your operation finished.
2. you should not call CancelIo

however i think that use `GetOverlappedResult` for asynchronous i/o at all no sense. need use apc or iocp completion.

Comment: thanks, yes I work with serial port. I use GetOverlappedResult to supply a sync operation. :)

Comment: @BianChengNan - i be on your place bind iocp to file handle via `BindIoCompletionCallback` and work asynchronous, instead wait in place. however this is your choice. about `GetOverlappedResult` unfortunately this is error in api implementation. i be advice look for           `(NTSTATUS)pOverlapped->Internal` - this give you correct result of operation. that *The Internal member was originally reserved for system use and its behavior may change* - this is conscious lie - this will be not changed and can not be changed

Comment: @BianChengNan - you of course can use own iocp, but think for your task the best use or `BindIoCompletionCallback` (you got `STATUS_TIMEOUT` in callback, in callback you at all got `NTSTATUS` values or (vista+) `CreateThreadpoolIo` - but here you got win32 error code in callback and again **lost** `STATUS_TIMEOUT`. so I be advice exactly `BindIoCompletionCallback` use